# action link to data table MVC

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Am trying to add link on a table using MVC . This is how i use to do it:

```
  <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit Roles", "Edit", "Users", new { userName = "User\\" + u.UserName }, new { @class = "action" }) </td>
```

Which works ...

But now i need to implement this to a datatable in Jquery. what i have so far is :

cshtml:

```
{ 
 "mDataProp": function (source, type, val) {
      return '<a href="/Home/Edit/'+source.UserName+'">Edit Roles</a>'

 }, "bSortable": false
},
```

Controller:

```
          public ActionResult EditRole(string UserName)
    {
        return View("editRole", new UserForm(UserName));
    }
```

The problem is how do i get

```
  new { userName = "User\\" + u.UserName },
```

to be called in here:

```
      return '<a href="/Home/Edit/'+source.UserName+'">Edit Roles</a>'
```

at the moment it doesnt work, it finds the username but says 404 error as the url becomes Home/Edit/Username (which it cant find...) as it only can find: Home/Edit/
any help will be appreciated...

Comment: why don't you just use the scaffolding MVC provides for CRUD operations??

Comment: because its been developed using jquery datatable, so am just carrying it on

Comment: can you show the html generated by the mvc link

Comment: its a blank page av not really put anything in. i need to get the user id to pass first

Comment: I mean @Html.ActionLink() must generate something like this <a href="/Home/Edit/MyUserName">Edit Roles</a>

Comment: return '<a href="/Home/Edit/?UserName='+source.UserName+'">Edit Roles</a>'

Comment: Or return '<a href="/Home/Edit/User?UserName='+source.UserName+'">Edit Roles</a>' It's not clear you want the final url to look like.

Comment: @markpsmith thanks thats what iv been looking for!!! ?UserName='

Comment: If its not finding `Home/Edit/Username` its because you routes are not mapped correctly. Do you have a route with`url: "/Home/Edit/{UserName}",`? (the default is a parameter named `id`, but yours is `UserName`)